# How to best make treat promise rejection like uncaught exception?

Tags: node.js, promise

If there are unhandled Promise rejections, Node.js currently just logs an error, with a mention that in the future such errors will cause a process to exit.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. How to best make Node.js today treat unhandled Promise rejections such that it exits the process?
2. If the failure of some promise is, in effect, the same as an uncaught exception and should cause exiting the process, how to best make that happen?

There are obviously lots of ways to do this, but I am trying to find the cleanest and simplest way that would not require me to make a new utility library just for this functionality.

Some candidates:

- `process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => { throw err; })` - might be confusing as nothing shows it is from a promise, instead of just a thrown exception, and also not usable in `.catch()`.
- `process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => { console.error(err); process.exit(1); })`

Comment: How about having a `.catch()` at the end of all your promise chains?

Comment: But what to add there that would exit the process nicely with a decent message?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases you almost never want your node `server` to `exit` when there is an `exception` or `error`. The very job of error handler (`try/catch` and `.catch()`) is to make sure your server stay up and running even when there is an `exception` or `error`.

Rather, when you get an `exception` or `error`, you should:

1. `catch` that  `error` and `throw` a custom `error` with a specific `error` message (and `error` code  if that suits you).
2. `catch` the custom `error` at the end of promise chain (or `app.use(err,...)`) and send that `error` message to the user.

Following is  a simple psudocode where the user is giving you `XML` and expects parsed `JSON` as a response:

```
function parseXML(xmlStr){
    return someParsingLibrary.parseXml2JSON(xmlStr)
        .catch(()=>{

            throw new Error("Your xml was not valid");
        })
}

app.post("/parse", function (req, res, next) {
    let xmlStr = req.body.xml;
    parseXML(xmlStr)
        .then((json)=>{
            res.status(200).send({description:"Success", body:json});
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            res.status(422).send({description:err.message, body:err});
        })
});
```

Comment: Um, I'm talking about the handling of programming errors, for which the best course of action is to exit immediately. Please see https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors

Comment: Even if you have bug in your api, like reading property of undefined, you still shouldn't exit. Other users who are using other apis should get served. Programming error and other unpredictable errors are caught at last by `app.use(err,...)` and in that you send something like: `res.status(500).send({description:"Some problem with server", body:err});`